# How to make d3 bar chart bins' width resize properly on update?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a d3 bar chart in my angular application. As I pull in new data, the number of bins along the x-axis changes, but the bins do not resize and shift appropriately. On load, the bins are aligned with axis ticks properly, but after that changes, there are spacing and alignment issues. Can someone tell me how to make the bins dynamic and update properly like the axis already does?

I reproduced my problem on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-bin-resize-error

The code I use to update the chart is here:

```
async draw() {
    var color_scale = this.color_scale;
    var height = this.hght;
    var filteredCountsData = await this.filterData();

    var t = d3.transition()
        .duration(2000);

    var max_value = d3.max(filteredCountsData, function(d : any) {
        return +d.count;
    });
    var x_scale = this.x_scale.domain(filteredCountsData.map(function(d) {
        return d.category;
    }));

    var y_scale = this.y_scale.domain([0, max_value]);

    this.color_scale.domain([0, max_value]);

    var bars = this.svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(filteredCountsData);

    bars
        .exit()
        .remove();

    var new_bars = bars
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', function(d : any) {
            return x_scale(d.category);
        })
        .attr('width', x_scale.bandwidth())
        .attr('y', height)
        .attr('height', 0)

    new_bars.merge(bars) // @ts-ignore
        .transition(t)
        .attr('width', x_scale.bandwidth())
        .attr('y', function(d : any) {
            return y_scale(+d.count);
        })
        .attr('height', function(d : any) {
            return height - y_scale(+d.count)
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return color_scale(+d.count);
        })

    this.svg.select('.x.axis')
        .transition(t)
        .call(this.x_axis);

    this.svg.select('.y.axis')
        .transition(t)
        .call(this.y_axis); // @ts-ignore
}
```

If you look at the stackblitz link and click on the change bins button until the number of bins changes, you can reproduce the spacing error.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot to set the `x` attribute in the `merge`. So the merge will result in:

```
    new_bars.merge(bars) // @ts-ignore
        .transition(t)
        .attr('width', x_scale.bandwidth())
        .attr('y', function(d : any) {
            return y_scale(+d.count);
        })
        .attr('x', function(d : any) {
            return x_scale(d.category);
        })
        .attr('height', function(d : any) {
            return height - y_scale(+d.count)
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return color_scale(+d.count);
        })
```